# Selenium: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed

Tags: selenium

1. System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\Selenium\jars\IEDriverServer\IEDriverServer.exe");
2. WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
3. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
4. driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com");
5. driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgot Password")).click();
6. Thread.sleep(3000);
7. driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("testmail@mail.com");

when i run the above code it is working fine with chrome and firefox but when i run using IE it is throwing below error when running **7th step** don't understand y it is not working in IE.

**Could some one please help me in resolve this issue. Thanks in advance**

Nov 20, 2017 2:58:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
**INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)**

**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed.**
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'ML-SIVAKUMARS-P', ip: '192.168.12.159', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{proxy=Proxy(), acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:2761/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=WINDOWS, setWindowRect=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: 24a4d291-482e-4399-98fc-f2037c4da5bb
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=email}

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
at com.org.learning.tests.TestDayTwo.firstTest(TestDayTwo.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem since yesterday and finally got my test to work.
Check if you have all the [required configurations](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) for the InternetExplorerDriver. For me it was the protected mode settings which I finally tested even though I am on Win 10.
Hope it helps you, too.

Comment: Many Thanks Zucchini. It's working by setting. **For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.**. You saved my time, once again thanks

Comment: The following error should be happened if Protected Mode settings are not the same:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.

Comment: Thank you <3 you saved me like zillion hours!

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways:

**Way 1:** Setting INITIAL_BROWSER_URL:

```
File ieFile = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieFile.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities ieCaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, "http://www.bing.com/");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCaps);
//some operations on that site
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).sendKeys("Ripon Al Wasim");
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_go")).click();
```

**Way 2:** To set a registry entry on the target computer:
For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

***For 32-bit Windows:*** The key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

***For 64-bit Windows:*** The key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.

***Note:*** Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

[image]

For more details you can visit: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Answer (score 3):

There are three Settings :

1. Zoom level set to 100%
2. Unchecked the Internet Options --> Security--> For Internet and Trusted sites
3. Unchecked "Enable Protected Mode"

Answer (score 3):

Error resolved in my case after enabling protected mode in internet explorer.

Settings--> internet options-->security --> check Enbale protected mode for all the zones.

Comment: In my case, it was already enabled. I disabled it and re-enabled to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the error due to missing slash at last of URL "/"

Actual is `http://example.com/`
but I was passing `http://example.com`